# Send/receive data between android devices using phonegap bluetooth plugin not working

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, bluetooth

I'm experimenting with Phonegap Bluetooth Plugin (https://github.com/tanelih/phonegap-bluetooth-plugin) for days now, and found out that it works with Phonegap 2.7.0. It does not work with newer Phonegap releases... I could turn BT on/off, list paired devices, connect to device and start the connection manager. However, I couldn't send/receive data between two Samsung devices. Is it even possible? If yes, how can I send simple text from one device to another?

I've already connected the devices, and started the connection manager on both devices. When I send something, it says "OK", so there is no error. But there is no incoming data on the other device... I always use UUID "00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" to connect, other UUID's do not work... The connection manager is working, because if I turn off BT on one device, the other device is responding with an error message.

I hope there is a way to send data from one device to another ( I use Galaxy S3 and Galaxy Tab 3). Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin doesn't include the feature of listening to incoming connections and receiving data from them. It only allows you to connect to a device and then perform write and read operations to the `BluetoothSocket` it opens. For example with some portable GPS-system.

The reason you are not seeing data on the other end is because the `ConnectionManager` handles just one-way connections. Like client to server. Now you are creating two different connections and thus the data is not shared between them. You would need an "`AcceptThread`" on the other device for it to accept the connection the other device would attempt using the `ConnectionAttempt` and `ConnectionManager` threads.

Comment: Hi, im new to phonegap and facing same problem for sending a file to another device using bluetooth for phonegap. please can u share me the source code to my mail ID: s.sarann7@gmail.com that would be more helpfull. Thanks and awaiting..